# validating form elements only on submit event with validate() method

Tags: jquery, validation

by default in [validate() jQuery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/) all input element inside a form  validate when loses focus or on typing everything on it . but i want to validate my form only on submit it for all element.  Is there any way for this problem?
this is my Code . message is written in persian language:

```
$('form#form_login').validate({
        rules: {
            user :{
                required  : true ,
                user_char : true,
                minlength : 4 ,
                maxlength : 12
            },
            pass :{
                required  : true ,
                user_char : true,
                minlength : 4 ,
                maxlength : 12
            }
        },
        messages:{
            user :{
                required   : ' لطفا شناسه کاربری را وارد نمایید ',
                user_char  : ' فقط حروف ، اعداد و _ برای شناسه کاربری مجاز است ', 
                minlength  : ' شناسه کاربری می بایست حداقل 4 کاراکتر باشد ',
                maxlength  : ' شناسه کاربری می بایست حداکثر 12 کاراکتر باشد '
            },
            pass :{
                required   : ' لطفا کلمه عبور را وارد نمایید ',
                user_char  : ' فقط حروف ، اعداد و _ برای کلمه عبور مجاز است ', 
                minlength  : ' کلمه عبور می بایست حداقل 4 کاراکتر باشد ',
                maxlength  : ' کلمه عبور می بایست حداکثر 12 کاراکتر باشد '
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            alert(error.text());
        },
        onfocusout: false,
        onkeyup: false,
        onclick: false
     });
```

Comment: can you post your code and a link to the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the focus, keyup and click handlers by doing this:

```
$(".selector").validate({
   onfocusout: false,
   onkeyup: false,
   onclick: false
});
```

Check out the options in the docs:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

Comment: thanks.but by this solution when on submit the form all error message display Twice!